# Finding area between two curves using double integral

Tags: calculus

Find the area between two curves:

- $x \ge 0$
- $(x^2+y^2)^2=x^2-y^2$

using double integrals.

Comment: How far can you get with this?  Can you set up the double integral, but you can't compute the value?  Can you not figure out what region of the plane is intended?  Please add some context.

Comment: I don't know how to write boundaries in those integrals, and area that i'm trying to find is when $x\ge0$

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%5E2%3Dx%5E2-y%5E2

Comment: Being more precisely, if you put this wierd equation in wolframalpha on graph it looks like infinity sign, iwant to compute the area inside this but only on the right hand side when x>0, and i have no ideas how to find integrating boundaries

Comment: It doesn't look infinite to me.  Have you considered switching to polar coordinates?

Comment: i mean "infinity symbol" not infinity

Comment: I am sorry, in this case i was probably asked to use polar coordinates. But i haven't read a lecture about it yet

Comment: Oh $\infty$; I understand now.  Yeah, it's called a lemniscate.  To do it without polar coordinates, you have to solve for $y$ in terms of $x$.  Note that it's a quadratic in $y^2$.  I haven't done it, so I don't know what the integral is like.  Anyway, that's where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to polar coordinates

$$ r= \sqrt{\cos 2 \theta}$$

Area in first quadrant

$$=\int_0 ^{\pi/4} r^2/2\; d\theta = \int \frac12 {\cos 2 \theta} \;d\theta =\dfrac{\sin 2 \theta}{4}|^{\pi/4}_0 = \frac 14 $$

For $x\ge0$ area is to be doubled.

Comment: how did u find boundary pi/4 ?

Comment: $ r= \sqrt{\cos 2 \theta} =0; $ Solving $ \theta = \pm \pi/4 $  It is called the Lemniscate of Bernoulli.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the area:

[image]

Solve $(x^2 + y^2)^2 = x^2 − y^2$ for $y(x)$ and get four solutions, restrict to positive $x$ to find:

$$y(x) = \pm \sqrt{2} \sqrt{-1 - 2 x^2 + \sqrt{1 + 8 x^2}}$$

so:

$$\int\limits_{x=0}^1 2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{-1 - 2 x^2 + \sqrt{1 + 8 x^2}}\ dx = \frac{1}{2}$$

(I have no idea why there might be a need for a *double* integral.)

Comment: I got that far, and decided to use polar coordinates instead.  How does one compute the integral?

Comment: how you found out pattern for y(x) ?